# Is Lego: Legends Of Chima Laval's Journey open world?

Tags: ps-vita, lego-legends-chima-lavals-journey

Is Laval's Journey open world on the PS Vita or even has just open world elements?

Googling the issue seems to present mixed answers. Some say it's open world, some say it has open world elements, and others claim it isn't open world at all, while still others claim it isn't on the 3DS but is on the Vita. Videos on Youtube also don't give a real answer.

Is there anyone who actually owns the game on Vita that could give a final answer to the question?